# Dell 3190 won't boot from Ubuntu Usb

Tags: usb

I am unable to boot from a Ubuntu startup usb on my new Dell Inspiron 3190. The usb was made with Ubuntu startup usb creation tool yesterday. I have put the usb drive 1st in boot order in the bios. But booting with the usb in the slot, the computer goes straight to Win 11. If I go to one-time start menu (f12) and choose the usb startup drive from there, the BIOS gives me this message: "operating system loading signature found in secure boot exclusion database (*dbx). All bootable devices failed Secureboot verification" Looks like my Ubuntu usb is on some kind of block list. How might I get off such a list?

Most comments on the web say turn off secure boot. In this bios that is not possible. Also a Win 11 usb starts up with no problem.

Comment: Have you checked the usb media is working in another computer? It might just be a corrupted iso.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue has been discussed in [this StackExchange article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723279/operating-system-loader-signature-found-in-secureboot-exclusion-database-dbx).
You could disable secure boot.
The message "All bootable devices failed Secure Boot verification." is an indication that it should be disabled for your linux distro to boot.
For Dell Latitude 3190, to disable secure boot, [this link](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-ae/latitude-11-3190-laptop/latitude_3190_owners_manual/secure-boot-screen-options?guid=guid-79aed1a8-1813-4e30-b752-da75c8e1d6ca&lang=en-us).